# SQL join on multiple columns into one

Tags: mysql, sql

Two tables:

```
airline(a_code, name);
serves(a_code, from_code, to_code)
```

I want to produce just two columns that will list all flights served by an airline (name, flight_code)

which should be something like

```
SELECT a_code,from_code as flight_code from airline NATURAL JOIN serves
UNION
SELECT a_code,to_code as flight_code from airline NATURAL JOIN serves
```

Intuition tells me there should be more efficient query.
maybe something like

```
SELECT name, **flight_code**
FROM airline JOIN serves
ON a_code = from_code **as_flight_code** OR a_code = to_code **as_flight_code_as_well**
```

But not sure how to resolve column name ambiguity then (is SELECT name, **a_code** going to work here?)

Comment: `ON a_code in (from_code,to_code)`

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `natural join`.  It will just make your code prone to errors, because you may not realize which columns are used for the `join`.

In fact, you don't need a `join` at all:

```
select s.a_code, from_code as flight_code
from serves s
where s.a_code = $a_code
union
select s.a_code, to_code
from serves s
where s.a_code = $a_code;
```

Otherwise your query is fine.  If you know that `from_code` and `to_code` are never the same, then use `union all` instead of `union`.